# CoreNLP runs too slow

Tags: stanford-nlp

I intend to use Corenlp to annotate some amazon reviews, however, I wait for over 6 hours, nothing output is produced.

```
 1. the review is about 1MB;
 2. the cluster has 12CPU, 64G memory;
 3. the command is 
 java -cp "*" -Xmx64g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,ner,sentiment -outputFormat json  -file amazon_apple_comments_4.csv
```

What has happened? is it so slow?

Answer (score 1):

That's waaaay too slow for a 1Mb document. Try running fewer annotators to narrow down which one is taking the most time. The `tokenize` and `ssplit` annotators should be extremely fast; `pos` is a bit slower, but not bad; `ner` is slower than `pos`, but in a 1Mb Amazon review, it shouldn't find many named entities. I've never used `sentiment`, but I imagine that it's nontrivial.